# RabbitMQ passing message back to the calling client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interface, rabbitmq

This is my first time trying to post a question on stackoverflow. Please bear with me if something is wrong in question or approach. I did lot of search to find an answer for my problem, not able to figure it out. This is what I am trying to do. I wrote a WCF service that connects to a RabbitMQ localhost to retrieve messages. I wrote a console program that uses the WCF service. Now I want whatever the messages the WCF picks up from RabbitMQ to be passed back to the console program and still the WCF is waiting to pick up any upcoming messages. The examples I saw were using delegates and events to pass the message back to a Windows Form Application. I am having difficulty implementing this for a console program. Below is my WCF Code.

```
public class MessageQueueSvc : IService1
{
    public string HOST_NAME = "localhost";
    public string EXCHANGE_NAME = "MyExchange";
    public string QUEUE_NAME = "MyMessageQ1";
    public string ROUTING_KEY = "";

    protected bool isConsuming;
    public delegate void onReceiveMessage(byte[] message);
    public event onReceiveMessage onMessageReceived;

    public IModel Model { get; set; }
    public IConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public Subscription mSubscription { get; set; }

    public string Hello(string name)
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public void StartConsuming()
    {
        isConsuming = true;

        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.HostName = "localhost";
        Connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();

        //connect the model, exchange, queue and bind them together
        bool durable = true;

        //after connection create a channel so that you can communicate with the broker thru this channel. 
        IModel channel = Connection.CreateModel();

        //after this declare an exchange and a queue and bind them together to this channel 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EXCHANGE_NAME))
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, ExchangeType.Direct, durable);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(QUEUE_NAME))
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            channel.QueueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, null);
        }

        //once model,exchange, queue is created then start cosuming it. 
        bool autoAck = false;

        //create a subscription
        mSubscription = new Subscription(Model, QUEUE_NAME, autoAck);

        while (isConsuming)
        {
            BasicDeliverEventArgs e = mSubscription.Next();
            byte[] body = e.Body;
            String tempStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            tempStr = "Processed message = " + tempStr;
            body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempStr);
            if (onMessageReceived != null)
            {
                //this is not working. I have to write an event handler or some sort of delegate to pass the message back to the calling program
                //and still waiting here for further messages from the server. 
                onMessageReceived(body);
            }
            mSubscription.Ack(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to narrow down the possible causes.  Can you get messages out of RabbitMQ without using a WCF Service? It's hard to tell if the queue is event available, can connect to it the way you are, if there's a permissions issue, etc.

Comment: I verified. I can connect and pull the messages out of rabbitmq. For example if my message is "Test", when I hover over tempstr variable it has the value "Processed message = Test". There is no problem in receiving messages from Rabbit. The issues is how do i send those received messages to my console program.

Comment: What is your reason for using WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is slightly wrong.

You'll need to create the connection, channel and consumer when instantiating the MessageQueueSvc class, like what you are currently doing in the `StartConsuming` method. However, I wouldn't create an infinite loop to do the message consumption.

Instead when the console app calls the WCF client you should then consume from the queue.

```
public string GetMessage()
{
  BasicDeliverEventArgs e = mSubscription.Next();
  byte[] body = e.Body;
  String tempStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
  tempStr = "Processed message = " + tempStr;
  body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempStr);
  mSubscription.Ack(e);

  if (onMessageReceived != null)
  {
    return tempStr;
  } 
  else
  {
    return null; //or throw some kind of exception...
  }
}
```

Comment: Kzhen thanks for answering and your inputs. The main issue I am trying to solve here is, how do I pass those received messages back to the console program. I think I should be using delegate and events, but how? if you see my declaration of delegate and event and how I try to use, you can see the problem. I know its not a great idea to have delegates in interfaces, but I want someway to pass those messages back to my console program and print them in there.

Comment: Have you looked at how to PUSH data to clients via WCF - something like http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721

Comment: It would be nice to know your rationale for using WCF...?

Comment: kzhen, I am looking at the link you provided. I wanted to use WCF services to decouple some of the operations that we do.

Comment: I am not actively working on this issue right now. This issue took a back seat for me and how do I make this question answered or closed or whatever.

Comment: Ok, This is what I found or realized so far. My options are use a callback contract, duplex service.